# What string formats are guaranteed to always work in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, datetime

What string formats are **guaranteed** to always work in SQL Server, regardless of any settings?

I used to believe the only such format was '2018-09-13T14:41:07.123', always with both date and time, always with uppercase T separator, always with 3 places after the decimal.

So if I want to pass just a date, I'd have to use '2018-09-13T00:00:00.000'.

I believed that the same format, but with a space instead of T, was only guaranteed to work if using OLE or ODBC.

Now as I scan the documentation for the new date/time types, datetime2, datetimeoffset, I get confused.  The documentation will require the 'T', and then in the same breath they'll show an example with a space instead.

I'm not just interested in formats that work, or always work, or have always worked, ... I'm specifically asking for formats that are **guaranteed** to work according the Microsoft documentation.

I need the result to work in SQL Server 2008, but I would be interested to hear if there are newer guaranteed formats in newer versions.

Comment: The Microsoft documentation is nice and all, but [this answer is better](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/166772/97345).

Comment: There are only four guaranteed formats, but I don't think you'll ever get such definitive statements from Microsoft. `yyyy-mm-dd` for the `date` data type only. For all date/time types, `yyyymmdd`, `yyyymmdd hh:mm...`, and `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm...` are the only ones guaranteed to not be misinterpreted due to regional, language, or dateformat settings. If you see code samples in documentation with any other format, assume sloppiness, not intent.

Comment: " I'm specifically asking for formats that are guaranteed to work according the Microsoft documentation."   ...because you think we have access to some documentation that you don't?